# How do I show a vector in a vector space is unique?

Tags: linear-algebra

$U = \{(x, y, 0) \in F^3 : x, y ∈ F\}$ and $W = \{(0, 0, z) ∈ F^3 : z ∈ F\}$.

Verify that $F^3 = U \oplus W$.

---

Suppose I don't know that if $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$, then $V = U \oplus W$ if and only if $V = U + W$ and $U ∩ W = \{0\}$.

Here I must show that $v = (x, y, 0) + (0, 0, z)$ in $F^3$ is the only way $v$ can be written.

Thanks.

Comment: ... is the only way $v$ can be written as sum of a vector from $U$ and another from $W$.

Answer (score 1):

If $v = (x_1, y_1, 0) + (0, 0, z_1)$ and $v = (x_2, y_2, 0) + (0, 0, z_2)$, then

$$0 = v - v = (x_1 - x_2, y_1 - y_2, 0) + (0, 0, z_1 - z_2) = (x_1 - x_2, y_1 - y_2, z_1 - z_2)$$

which is equivalent to

$$\begin{cases}
x_1 - x_2 = 0 \\
y_1 - y_2 = 0 \\
z_1 - z_2 = 0
\end{cases}$$

Thus $x_1 = x_2$, $y_1 = y_2$ and $z_1 = z_2$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show that a vector $v$ can be uniquely represented in the form $u+w$, you can give the formula that provides such a representation. In your case this is pretty straightforward. Let $v=(a,b,c)\in F^3$, then $v$ can be written as $(a,b,0)+(0,0,c)$ (where $(a,b,0) \in U$ and $(0,0,c) \in W$). It is obvious that for a given vector (fixed values of $a,b$ and $c$) this representation is unique.

For example: there is only one way in which you can write the vector $(1,2,8)$ as a sum of $u\in U$ and $w\in W$: $(1,2,8)=(1,2,0)+(0,0,8)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how (a, b, c) is unique a little more? It might be obvious, but I am still not seeing it.